# Only displaying certain data from a json call

Tags: android, json, android-listview

I am parsing a json result and it is stored in a HashMap and then displaying it with a listview. The only thing wrong with it atm is that the day is being displayed twice (or three times), I want each day to only show once. I know it's displaying more than once at the moment because it's being coded that way, but I am unsure how to change it so it only displays once.

Json data

```
{
"Monday": [
    {
        "Day": "Monday",
        "Time": "09:15",
        "Title": "123"
    },
    {
        "Day": "Monday",
        "Time": "12:15",
        "Title": "456"
    }
],
"Tuesday": [
    {
        "Day": "Tuesday",
        "Time": "09:15",
        "Title": "789"
    },
    {
        "Day": "Tuesday",
        "Time": "10:15",
        "Title": "ABC"
    },
    {
        "Day": "Tuesday",
        "Time": "11:15",
        "Title": "DEF"
    }
]
}
```

I am using the adapter below to display the data to the screen. The "List" is the hashmap and "Day, Time and Title" are the 3 bits of information to display and the R.id.X are the textviews the information is going into.

```
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(Main.this, List, R.layout.main_layout, new String[] {DAY, TIME, TITLE}, new int[] {R.id.Day, R.id.Time, R.id.Title});
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

I think to achieve the day being only shown once, I need to have multiple listviews and have only monday displayed in the first listview, tuesday in the next etc, but I don't know how to do that. I tried putting tuesday into a second hashmap and adapter, but that just overwrote the information in the first adapter. 
Would my idea be the best way to go about this or would there be a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should extends BaseAdapter and consider creating Listview with row more than simgle type.
One type will be your heading for day and second will show contents you want to show related to day.

---

This might help you http://antew.com/?p=162

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want by creating a custom adapter where you can specify what you need to show.

For instance, you can do something like:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends SimpleAdapter
{

    public CustomAdapter( Context context, List<? extends Map<String, ?>> data, int resource, String[] from, int[] to )
    {
        super( context, data, resource, from, to );
    }

    @Override
    public View getView( int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent )
    {
        if(some_condition/*whatever condition you want to show only days*/)
        {
            convertView.findViewById( R.id.Time ).setVisibility( View.GONE );
            convertView.findViewById( R.id.Title ).setVisibility( View.GONE );
        }
        else
        {
            convertView.findViewById( R.id.Time ).setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
            convertView.findViewById( R.id.Title ).setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
        }

        return convertView; 
    }
}
```

and then do:

```
ListAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(Main.this, List, R.layout.main_layout, new String[] {DAY, TIME, TITLE}, new int[] {R.id.Day, R.id.Time, R.id.Title});
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

You should also take a look at [Making ListView Scrolling Smooth](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html) which covers how to optimize adapters. The adapter I provided should work but is not efficient